# How to make redis BGSAVE run on a predefined schedule at fixed hours of the day

Tags: redis, schedule

I have a service that uses redis extensively, and redis `BGSAVE` is creating memory-usage spikes from time to time.

**I want to somehow schedule BGSAVE so that it could be run only on some specific hours of the day(like 2:00 AM) when server load is lower.**

I have seen `SCHEDULE` parameter added to `BGSAVE` command. however, as the documentation says, it is only used to run a `BGSAVE` command after an AOF rewrite is completed. So I was wondering if there is any way to schedule `BGSAVE` to run at specific hours of every day like a cron job.

I would prefer if this could be done by changing redis config file, rather than an external tool.

Comment: There's no way to do that. crontab should be a reliable and easy way to achieve your goal.

Comment: I know `crontab` is a reliable tool. However, it is not reliable in terms of consistency and easy migration process. It can easily be forgotten should we migrate our servers.

Comment: So make a mental note/migration procedure doc ;)

Comment: You can implement cron job to call Redis in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Shell Script: Create a shell script that performs the SAVE operation. For example, create a file named redis_backup.sh:

#!/bin/bash

redis-cli BGSAVE

Make sure to grant execute permissions to this script:

chmod +x redis_backup.sh

Use Cron to Schedule: You can use the cron utility to schedule the script to run at a specific time, such as 2:00 AM. Edit your crontab file by running:

crontab -e

Add the following line to schedule the script to run at 2:00 AM:

0 2 * * * /path/to/redis_backup.sh